# phantomjs: command not found

Tags: phantomjs, sh

I'm using the code provided by this [blog post](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html) to capture the snapshot of an Angular page, but when I try to run

```
./make-snapshot.sh http://localhost:5757/#!/home
```

I get the error

```
phantomjs: command not found
```

Here's the contents of that file:

```
U=$1
P=$( echo "$U" | perl -MURI -le 'chomp($url = <>); print URI->new($url)->fragment' )
final_url=$U
P=${P:1}
final_path=./snapshots$P.html
phantomjs .phantomjs-runner.js $final_url > $final_path
```

More details are on this [page](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html).

phantomjs  works on my terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was , when i cloned this repo, it never downloaded the file .phantom-runner.js .

It works now!